How to Add JWT Token Support Globally in Scalar for a .NET 9 Application?
I'm working on enabling Scalar in my .NET 9 application and need to configure it to use JWT tokens globally, similar to how Swagger allows adding JWT token authentication globally. However, I couldn't find any documentation or examples on how to achieve this with Scalar.
Is it possible to set up global JWT token support in Scalar? If so, how can this be implemented? Any examples or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
//other codes
services.AddOpenApi();
//other codes
app.MapOpenApi();
app.MapScalarApiReference(options =>
{
    options.WithTheme(ScalarTheme.Moon)
        .WithDarkMode(true)
        .WithDefaultHttpClient(ScalarTarget.CSharp, ScalarClient.HttpClient)
        .WithDarkModeToggle(false)
        .WithPreferredScheme("Bearer")
        .WithHttpBearerAuthentication(bearer =>
        {
            bearer.Token = "your-bearer-token";
        });
    options.Authentication = new ScalarAuthenticationOptions
    {
        PreferredSecurityScheme = "Bearer"
    };
});

Packages:

Scalar.AspNetCore (1.2.49)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi (9.0.0)


Credit to this post : https://github.com/scalar/scalar/issues/4055
There is an issue with the auth type loading ;)
Replace this ->
builder.Services.AddOpenApi();

with that ->
builder.Services.AddOpenApi("v1", options => { options.AddDocumentTransformer<BearerSecuritySchemeTransformer>(); });

internal sealed class BearerSecuritySchemeTransformer(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.IAuthenticationSchemeProvider authenticationSchemeProvider) : IOpenApiDocumentTransformer
{
    public async Task TransformAsync(OpenApiDocument document, OpenApiDocumentTransformerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var authenticationSchemes = await authenticationSchemeProvider.GetAllSchemesAsync();
        if (authenticationSchemes.Any(authScheme => authScheme.Name == "Bearer"))
        {
            var requirements = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiSecurityScheme>
            {
                ["Bearer"] = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                    Scheme = "bearer", 
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    BearerFormat = "Json Web Token"
                }
            };
            document.Components ??= new OpenApiComponents();
            document.Components.SecuritySchemes = requirements;

            foreach (var operation in document.Paths.Values.SelectMany(path => path.Operations))
            {
                operation.Value.Security.Add(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    [new OpenApiSecurityScheme { Reference = new OpenApiReference { Id = "Bearer", Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme } }] = Array.Empty<string>()
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

Then you should see something like this
Scalar ui
